# If $a$ and $b$ is $> 1$, and $p=\frac{\log_{b}(\log_{b}{a})}{\log_ba}$ what is $a^p$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> If $a$ and $b$ is $> 1$, and $p=\frac{\log_{b}(\log_{b}{a})}{\log_ba}$ what is $a^p$?

I wasn't even sure on how to start (don't vote down simply because I don't show work I do not know on how to start the problem

Comment: You start with $a^p = b^{p \log_b a}$, now substitute for $p$.

Answer (score 3):

Using the change of basis formula, namely $\log_a X=\dfrac{\log_b X}{\log_b a}$, we get
$$p=\log_a\left(\log_ba\right)$$
So $a^p=\log_ba$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $c=\log_b b$ i.e. $b^c=a$:
$$\begin{align}
p&=\frac {\log_b(\log_b a)}{\log_b a}
=\frac {\log_b c}c\\
cp&=\log_b c\\
c&=b^{cp}
=(b^c)^p
=a^p\\
a^p&=\color{red}{\log_b a}\end{align}$$